# Carousel component a-la searchme.com

Tags: flash, user-interface

I'm looking for an open source flash carousel component similar to what searchme.com has.

Comment: Well, I guess I need flash. The javascript are not that slick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:
http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/11/03/coverflow-flex-component/

There is a possibility to do this really nicely using flash papervision which is a 3d library for action script.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MooFlow](http://www.outcut.de/MooFlow/example-ajax.html).

There is also [ImageFlow](http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/).